# Bar charts: Change the vertical order of different plots and corresponding legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to compare percentages of two different years using horizontal bar charts.

The values for the 2 years (1996 and 2011) are given via a pgfplots table. I want the 1996 values to be shown in top of the corresponding 2011 values. But when adding them in the correct order, the legend entries are ordered the other way (2011 shown first, then 1996).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Type,1996,2011
type1,41.26,46.57
type2,55.42,38.76
type3,0.14,0.11
type4,0.24,0.05
type5,0.79,13.20
type6,2.14,1.31
}\data

\begin{figure} [tb]%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[    
            width=12cm,
            xbar,                                 
            xtick={0,10,20,...,100},    
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,       
            grid=major,
            nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            symbolic y coords={type6,type5,type4,type3,type2,type1},
            ylabel={Type},
            xlabel={Percentage},
            y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}},
            enlarge x limits={abs=0}
        ]
        \addplot table [x=1996, y=Type] {\data};
        \addplot table [x=2011, y=Type] {\data};
        \legend{1996,2011}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:distribution}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried to change the legend order manually, like described in [this post](http://pgfplots-features.706524.n3.nabble.com/Pgfplots-features-Controlling-the-order-of-legend-entries-td2247179.html), but that led to ugly vertical align between bars and text in the legend:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Type,1996,2011
type1,41.26,46.57
type2,55.42,38.76
type3,0.14,0.11
type4,0.24,0.05
type5,0.79,13.20
type6,2.14,1.31
}\data

\begin{figure} [tb]%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[    
            width=12cm,
            xbar,                                 
            xtick={0,10,20,...,100},    
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,       
            grid=major,
            nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            symbolic y coords={type6,type5,type4,type3,type2,type1},
            ylabel={Type},
            xlabel={Percentage},
            y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}},
            enlarge x limits={abs=0},
            extra description/.code={
         \matrix[/pgfplots/every axis legend]
         {
                        \ref{1996} \pgfmatrixnextcell \node{1996};\\
                        \ref{2011} \pgfmatrixnextcell \node{2011};\\             
         };
         } 
        ]       
        \addplot table [x=2011, y=Type] {\data};        
        \label{2011}        
        \addplot table [x=1996, y=Type] {\data};
        \label{1996}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:distribution}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As suggested in the post, I consulted the `tikz` manual, but found no solution for this problem (at least for my latex skills). Any hints?

Comment: oh. that's indeed what I was searching for. So easy. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some key called `reverse legend` which should do exactly what you want.

Adding it to the option list yields

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Type,1996,2011
type1,41.26,46.57
type2,55.42,38.76
type3,0.14,0.11
type4,0.24,0.05
type5,0.79,13.20
type6,2.14,1.31
}\data

\begin{figure} [tb]%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[    
            width=12cm,
            xbar,                                 
            xtick={0,10,20,...,100},    
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100,       
            grid=major,
            nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            symbolic y coords={type6,type5,type4,type3,type2,type1},
            ylabel={Type},
            xlabel={Percentage},
            y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}},
            enlarge x limits={abs=0},
            reverse legend,
        ]
        \addplot table [x=2011, y=Type] {\data};
        \addplot table [x=1996, y=Type] {\data};
        \legend{2011,1996}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:distribution}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]